# Angularfire add class if loggedIn

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

I have an AngularFire app, generated with the angularfire yeoman generator. I'm using a directive that allows me to directly edit elements in the view when I'm logged in. For example:

```
<h1 contenteditable ng-model="foo.bar"></h1>
```

This directive comes straight from the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#example).

My Firebase security rules are pretty basic at the moment:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null"
    }
}
```

I'm using the following styles to add a dashed border around all editable content:

```
[contenteditable] {
  &:hover {
    outline: #ccc 2px dashed;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
}
```

I would like to scope this style to a logged-in state.

For instance:

```
.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope, simpleLogin, user) {
$scope.userLoggedIn = function() {
  if ($scope.user) {
    return true;
  }
}
<body ng-class="{loggedIn: userLoggedIn()}">
```

I don't really understand how the auth stuff works. Is there a simple way to go accomplishing my goal of adding a class based on whether or not a user is logged in? Is there another/better way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for AngularFire here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication, you will see that they show/hide an element based on whether a user is logged in with `<div ng-show="user">` and `<div ng-hide="user">`. Although this is not adding a class to the element, you can accomplish the same with it.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the reply. Looks like I'll have to update to the current version of Firebase to use that feature. I'm currently using 1.0.x.

Comment: I've used that ng-show combined with Firebase auth since 0.8, so no need to update. See this app for an example: https://trenches.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Thanks, Frank... I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question**, here: Turns out, the `yo angularfire` generator creates a simpleLogin.js file that handles the login and logout functions. I just added a little DOM manipulation to the functions and this yields the desired result of toggling the class on the body element.

```
login: function(provider, opts) {
          angular.element('body').addClass('isLoggedIn');
          return auth.$login(provider, opts);
        },

        logout: function() {
          auth.$logout();
          angular.element('body').removeClass('isLoggedIn');
        }
```